# How To Debug (Invisible) Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS )

Tags: pagespeed-insights, cls

When running a speed test on https://rc.swisswebcams.ch/webcam/1242547979 I get a CLS of **1.24** which is quite high. However, when looking at the screenshots and the suggestions below, I can't see any reason for this. Do I miss something here? How can I see the reason for this number?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the diagnostics you get a list of all the shifts:

[image: Screenshot of the layout shifts diagnostics]

In this example the footer was the most shifted element. This can happen if you have something like this:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<footer>
Some footer content
</footer>
```

When the app is inserted in the footer moves down.

Or if the app contains the footer but inserts it first before the main content, and then shifts it down.

Comment: OK, thanks - but regarding to the screenshots it's not an issue... how do you solve this usually?

Comment: PS: If you add up the CLS values in the list below (0.217, 0.021, ...) you don't get `1.24` - that's a bit confusing (by now I think I have optimized it, so it won't be reproducable anymore)

Comment: I only saw 0.24 when I did my test. I presume you saw more in this section from your test and presumed you optimised it since posting.

Comment: It's hard to say in retrospect, you might be right. However, something is a bit off for sure with this test, I posted it separately on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77556834/lighthouse-eval-js-is-listed-as-a-javascript-issue