# _lighthouse-eval.js is listed as a JavaScript issue

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Is this already a known issue? When looking at the diagnosis, https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-rc-swisswebcams-ch-webcam-1511343694/8v61s1j13f?form_factor=mobile lists itself as an issue which makes the test harder to interpret:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I work on Lighthouse.

> Is this a known issue?

It is now! Thanks for reporting, we'll have a [fix](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/pull/15678) in a future release soon.

A bit on the issue: yes, it's wrongly showing you some code that Lighthouse executed itself to get some data on the page. It's probably related to heavy graphics API usage, and unfortunately in PSI that is quite exacerbated by lack of GPU.

I haven't been able to reproduce getting "_lighthouse-eval.js" to show up in PSI - did you perhaps change anything about the page since ~11 days ago?

Comment: Thanks! Well, I have usually a couple of changes during the week. But when I opened the pagespeed URL posted in the question right now, I still get `_lighthouse-eval.js` showing up.